# Video turn power off phone problem

Tags: android

I have videoView , i load the video from the sdcard on method oncreate(), when i turn power off the phone and then turn the power on , the video is black screen , Any one knows why ? and what method is the activity call in this case onResume , onRestart ,... or what ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: When you turn the phone off it goes through the entire lifecycle

Comment: I don't get it.. Then what method it calls :S

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue, some high api version device have the same issue.

My solution is when the fragment or activity is:

onPause: stop and release all video datasource
   onResume: reset the datasource and replay the video.

and it solve the issue.

Hope it can help you.